# what different between sess.run two times or one time with tf.control_dependencies in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

I define a tensorflow model and want to train it by my own optimizer. but I meet a problem.

the following code ignore the defination of model, keeping only the optimizing part.

```
P = tf.global_variables()

lr = 0.1

update_ops = []
grads1 = tf.gradients(loss, P)

for p,g in zip(P, grads1):
    update_ops.append(tf.assign(p, p - lr * g))


with tf.control_dependencies(update_ops):

    update_ops_2 = []
    grads2 = tf.gradients(loss, P)

    for p,g in zip(P, grads2):
        update_ops_2.append(tf.assign(p, p - lr * g))
```

I run looply:

```
for i in range(1000):

    _ = sess.run(update_ops_2, feed_dict={myinput: mydata})
```

but the loss can not decrease, but I run

```
for i in range(1000):
    for j in range(2):
        _ = sess.run(update_ops, feed_dict={myinput: mydata})
```

the loss can decrease.

what different between them? how can I do if I want to get gradients twice in one `sess.run` ？

Answer (score 0):

Optimization in this code sample works smoothly, can you provide full of your code?

```
import tensorflow as tf
# from tensorflow.python.ops.resource_variable_ops import ResourceVariable

# x = ResourceVariable(2.)
x = tf.Variable(2.)
loss = tf.square(x)
P = tf.global_variables()

lr = 0.1

update_ops = []
grads1 = tf.gradients(loss, P)

for p, g in zip(P, grads1):
    update_ops.append(tf.assign(p, p - lr * g))


with tf.control_dependencies(update_ops):

    update_ops_2 = []
    grads2 = tf.gradients(loss, P)

    for p, g in zip(P, grads2):
        update_ops_2.append(tf.assign(p, p - lr * g))


sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
for i in range(20):
    _, l, xx = sess.run((update_ops_2, loss, x))
    print(l, xx)
```